# How to add ID to all li in list using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<ul class="list">
<li class="item">Item 1</li>
<li class="item">Item 2</li>
<li class="item">Item 3</li>
<li class="item">Item 4</li>
<li class="item">Item 5</li>
<li class="item">Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

I want to add ID for all li tags, use pure javascript. I am new, looking forward to helping everyone

http://jsfiddle.net/8XN8j/32/

Comment: You want to add id dynamically in the code or what? Please show me your code. I cannot access to jsfiddle

Comment: Always include the relevant parts of your code here, users shouldn't have to go to a secondary site to view it

Comment: Yep. Automatically like .each of jquery. But I'm using pure javascript. I do not know how to code.

Comment: Sorry. I will be more careful in posting. This is the first time, I will work better. Help me. Thank you.

Comment: var element  = document.querySelector('.list li');

element.forEach(i) {
 element.setAttribute("id", 'item'+(i+1));
}

Comment: You will learn a lot if you do a little bit of Rnd and read docs like "what is the difference between `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`"? What does `element` returns after `querySelectorAll`? Can we iterate through nodelist or just array using `forEach`? etc.

Comment: var element  = document.querySelector('.list li');

    element.forEach(i) {
 element.setAttribute("id", 'item'+(i+1));
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all elements using [`Document#querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method and then convert NodeList into array for iterating using [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.

```js
// get all elements
var element = document.querySelectorAll('.list li');
// convert NodeList into an array
// for older browser use [].slice.call(element)
Array.from(element)
  // iterate over the element
  .forEach(function(ele, i) {
    // generate and set id
    ele.setAttribute("id", 'item' + (i + 1));
  })
```

```css
#red {
  color: red;
}

#item1 {
  color: red;
}

#item2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="item">Item 3</li>
  <li class="item">Item 4</li>
  <li class="item">Item 5</li>
  <li class="item">Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass in a callback function to the forEach function. Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach for more info.
This is how you do it with ES6.

```js
var element  = document.querySelectorAll('.list li');

element.forEach((e, i) => {
 e.setAttribute("id", 'item'+(i+1));
});
```

```css
#red {
  color: red;
}

#item1 {
  color: red;
}

#item2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item">Item 3</li>
    <li class="item">Item 4</li>
    <li class="item">Item 5</li>
    <li class="item">Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hidingmode/Ltkoe8y0/1/

Answer (score 0):

Simply use as below.

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll(".list li");

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  const li = list[i];
  li.id = `item-${i}`;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="item">Item 3</li>
  <li class="item">Item 4</li>
  <li class="item">Item 5</li>
  <li class="item">Item 6</li>
</ul>
```